# Android: Working with Notification Buttons in Expanded Custom Layout

Tags: android, button, android-intent, notifications

So I've looked over a fair amount of Stackoverflow questions, but I'm still not having any luck getting this to work. I'm playing around with and trying to learn how to create and work with Notifications (trying to get the current system down before trying out the Wear API) and I'm running into a little bit of a roadblock. For Jellybean+, I have an expanded notification that includes three buttons. I want to be able to allow the user to click those buttons from the notification in order to perform an action (at this point it'd probably just be a log statement). So far I can't get the buttons to trigger anything. Right now my notification is created with this code:

```
private void showExpandedNotification() {
    RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.view_notification);
    expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.large_icon, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.ib_rewind, R.drawable.ic_rewind);
    expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.ib_play_pause, R.drawable.ic_play);
    expandedView.setImageViewResource(R.id.ib_fast_forward, R.drawable.ic_fast_forward);

    Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), CustomNotificationService.class );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.ib_play_pause, pendingIntent );

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .build();

    notification.bigContentView = expandedView;


    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

and I'm only setting an intent on one button. The service is pretty straight foward as I'm just trying to get it to work for now:

```
public class CustomNotificationService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.e( "CustomNotificationService", "onBind" );
    handleIntent( intent );
    return null;
}

private void handleIntent( Intent intent ) {
    if( intent != null && intent.getAction() != null ) {
        Log.e( "CustomNotificationService", intent.getAction().toString() );
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e( "CustomNotificationService", "onCreate()" );
}
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions or tutorials that they can point me to in order to get these buttons to send an intent or have a listener associated with them, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set click on Buttons in notification by doing as below :

```
 Intent playIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), CustomNotificationService.class );
 playIntent.putExtra("Button","Play");  
 PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( getApplicationContext(), 1, playIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.ib_play_pause, playPendingIntent );

 Intent rewindIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), CustomNotificationService.class );
 rewindIntent.putExtra("Button","Rewind");  
 PendingIntent rewindPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( getApplicationContext(), 2, rewindIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.ib_rewind, rewindPendingIntent );

 Intent fastForwardIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), CustomNotificationService.class );
 fastForwardIntent.putExtra("Button","FastForward");    
 PendingIntent fastForwardPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( getApplicationContext(), 3, fastForwardIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.ib_fast_forward, fastForwardPendingIntent );
```

Now in your service inside `handleInent()` do as below :

```
if( intent != null && intent.getAction() != null ) {
    String action= (String)getIntent().getExtras().get("Button");
    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Play")){
        Log.i("Info","Play Button clicked");           
    }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Rewind")){
            Log.i("Info","Rewind Button clicked");
    }else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("Forward")){
            Log.i("Info","Fast Forward Button clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, awesome. I came to a very similar conclusion and posted it just a couple seconds after you posted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PaulRuiz happy to hear that your problem is solved anyhow.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Added intent.setAction( "playpause" ); before creating the pendingintent, and then for the service I use

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleIntent( intent );
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

in order to grab the intent and pass it to my function, where I'm able to determine what kind of action is associated with it and perform my action.